# Undefined indexes in PHP. Generic solution required

Tags: php

I have been searching Stack Overflow and the rest of the web, and I am starting to believe that there is no generic solution for undefined indexes.

I have a massive PHP application with several form and at the end of the script I call all the form's inputs and put them together to display a summary of all the inputs.

```
echo $_POST['FirstName'];
echo $_POST['MiddleName'];
echo $_POST['LastName'];
```

I know how to check each occurence like

```
if ( !isset($_POST['MiddleName']) ) { $_POST['MiddleName'] = '' }
```

Is there a way to automatically capture all undefined indexes and then set them to 0 or null?

Answer (score 4):

It's as simple as looping trough an array of all indexes that may be defined:

```
   $indexes_that_MUST_be_defined_but_can_be_empty = array(
      'FirstName',
      * * *
      'LastName'
   );
   foreach($indexes_that_MUST_be_defined_but_can_be_empty as $index) {
       if( ! isset($_POST[$index])) {
           $_POST[$index] = NULL;
       }
   }
```

Or even you can preset different defaults like this:

```
   $indexes_that_MUST_be_defined_but_can_be_empty = array(
      'FirstName' => NULL,
      * * *
      'LastName' => NULL
   );
   $_POST = array_merge($indexes_that_MUST_be_defined_but_can_be_empty, $_POST);
```

If you really just want to suppress the warnings, you can use `@` like in:

```
echo htmlspecialchars(@$_POST['any_index']);
```

but I really don't recommend this.

**EDIT**:
Here's one more possible solution. A "magical" function that uses a pointer:

```
function null_if_not_defined(&$variable) {
    return isset($variable) ? $variable : NULL;
}

// Usage: 
echo htmlspecialchars(null_if_not_defined($_POST['any_index']));
```

Comment: +1, The way its been written in the app, its probably more like $indexes_that_MUST_be_defined_but_can_be_empty ;)

Comment: Core1024 this is excellent, do think it is possible to though to have a way of just saying that any undefined index is null rather than building the array(firstname,lastname etc). somethink like array (*)

Comment: No, you can't just define any undefined value to NULL. You can as other suggested use the `isset` function and ternary operator as test, define custom function to check or use any of my suggestions.

Answer (score 2):

You can do it using below function.

```
function setNullValue($arr)
{
    $newarr = array();
    foreach($arr as $key => $ar)
    {
        if($ar == "")
        {
            $newarr[$key] = 0;
        }
        else
        {
            $newarr[$key] = $ar;
        }
    }
    return $newarr;
}
print_r(setNullValue($_POST));
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to show only those indexes with assigned values, you could do something like this:

```
foreach ($_POST as $index => $value) {
  echo "{$index}: {$value}<br/>";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you can also create a simple function for this purpose:

```
$p = function($item) {
  return isset($_POST[$item]) ? $_POST[$item] : null;
};
```

Now you can use it as such :

```
echo $p('MiddleName');
```

Answer (score 0):

```
foreach($_POST as $key=>$value) {
 if($value == "") $_POST[$key] = 0;
}
```